# shell script to match column and add new columns into table from file

Tags: linux, shell, file, join, awk

I'm trying to write a shell script to compare two separate files, and add the x/y/objectID/Status/Data info to the first file, when the addresses and LocationID match. This is what my files look like:

FileA.csv:

```
MAC     LocationID     Node_ID     Street     City     State     Zip_Code
ABC123  182            AB12        25_Main_St Hanover  WZ        12345
CDE123  128            CD12        35_Main_St Hooray   TZ        23456
EFG123  812            EF12        45_Main_St Hello    WA        45678
```

FileB.csv

```
objectid  Status  Data   X        Y       LocationID     Node_ID     Street     City     State     Zip_Code
555       RRR     sss    123456   123444  182            AB12        25_Main_St Hanover  WZ        12345
666       GGG     ttt    234567    87978  128            CD12        35_Main_St Hooray   TZ        23456
777       RRR     uuu    54321     98765  812            EF12        45_Main_St Hello    WA        45678
```

I'm having trouble finding anything similar as an example for linux shell scripting.  Does anyone have a suggested way to join these two files?  The result would look like:

```
MAC       objectid  Status  Data   X        Y       LocationID     Node_ID     Street     City     State     Zip_Code
ABC123    555       RRR     sss    123456   123444  182            AB12        25_Main_St Hanover  WZ        12345
CDE123    666       GGG     ttt    234567   87978   128            CD12        35_Main_St Hooray   TZ        23456
EFG123    777       RRR     uuu    54321    98765   812            EF12        45_Main_St Hello    WA        45678
```

Note that the files aren't necessarily in the same order, and there are more lines in the Mac file than in the non-Mac file. The Mac file has duplicate LocationID's and addresses, but Mac's are all different.  The non-mac file will not have duplicate LocationID's or addresses.

Comment: Use `awk`. Read `FileB` into an array that uses the locationID as the keys. Then read `FileA` and merge the fields from the array into the current line and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR{k[$2]=$1; next} $6 in k{print k[$6], $0}' fileA fileB | column -t
```

```
MAC     objectid  Status  Data  X       Y       LocationID  Node_ID  Street      City     State  Zip_Code
ABC123  555       RRR     sss   123456  123444  182         AB12     25_Main_St  Hanover  WZ     12345
CDE123  666       GGG     ttt   234567  87978   128         CD12     35_Main_St  Hooray   TZ     23456
EFG123  777       RRR     uuu   54321   98765   812         EF12     45_Main_St  Hello    WA     45678
```

- `column -t` has been used to format the output in a tabular form.
- In 1st pass we process `fileA` and store 1st column with key as 2nd column in an associative array `k`
- In 2nd pass we process `fileB` and fetch mac address by using key as 6th column (i.e. LocationID) .

Comment: If there are comma's instead of spaces between the column info in the files, would anything change in your solution?

Comment: If files are comma delimited then use: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR == NR{k[$2]=$1; next} $6 in k{print k[$6], $0}' fileA fileB` with `column` command as `column -s ',' -t`